# How to send Ctrl+S through SendKeys.Send() method to save a file in an external application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sendkeys

I need to save a file which is in an external application using `SendKeys.Send()` method. The keys needed to be sent are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

I wrote the below code, but it does not work:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^%s?");  // to get the Save As dialog
Thread.Sleep(5000);
SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(null, "Save As"));
Thread.Sleep(5000);
SendKeys.SendWait("xyz"); // Sending FileName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to use:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)");
```

Instead of:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^%s?");
```

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.